# Dynamically Add and Remove HTML Elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to dynamically add and remove HTML elements to my product form (attribute addition purpose) and was searching stack overflow.

I found this solution to be very close (except it does not has a remove option plus I sincerely do not know how to retrieve the data of each textbox, but all this later).

https://jsfiddle.net/nzYAW/

The code in the fiddle works fine. But as I tried it on my local machine it fails to produce any result.

Here is what I did

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .extraPersonTemplate {display:none;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $('<div/>', {
                 'class': 'extraPerson',
                 html: GetHtml()
             }).appendTo('#container');
             $('#addRow').click(function () {
                 $('<div/>', {
                     'class': 'extraPerson',
                     html: GetHtml()
                 }).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');

             });
         })

         function GetHtml() {
             var len = $('.extraPerson').length;
             var $html = $('.extraPersonTemplate').clone();
             $html.find('[name=firstname]')[0].name = "firstname" + len;
             $html.find('[name=lastname]')[0].name = "lastname" + len;
             $html.find('[name=gender]')[0].name = "gender" + len;
             return $html.html();
         }    
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="extraPersonTemplate">
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input class="span3" placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="firstname">
        <input class="span3" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="lastname">
        <select class="span2" name="gender">
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<a href="#" id="addRow"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Add another family member</p></a>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the result

[image]

Where did I go wrong at copy paste?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to load jQuery library

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: great ho tussi ... chaa gaye

Comment: @ManishB, Shai hai, kuch english mein bhi likh de angrezo ke liye. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to include [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). If you check your [javascript console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) (which you definetly should) you will probably find this error:

```
$ is not defined
```

That is because jQuery wasn't loaded before you try to use it. Add this to your page before your javascript code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the JSFiddle that you include these libraries, but you don't include them when you just copy paste this.
Include these javascripts

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the JavaScript to be right above the `</body>` tag.

I think if you're trying to access elements before the page has loaded them, then it won't work.

Also as other answers have pointed out, be sure you've included jQuery in the `<head></head>` section of your page.